# Hibernate query for selecting values from a table with input from pathvariable

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have a rest api Spring MVC,database oracle sql developer and I am using hibernate for mapping.
I have a table Iteration.My code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{userid}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<IterationInfo> getIterationInfoInJSON(@PathVariable int userid) 
{
Configuration con = new Configuration();
con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory();
Session session= SF.openSession();
Transaction TR = session.beginTransaction();
Query query=session.createQuery("from IterationInfo");
List<IterationInfo> listiterationinfo=query.list();
session.close();

SF.close();
return listiterationinfo;
}
```

I want to fire a query select * from IterationInfo where userid=(The userid I get from the path variable).
Like from (@pathVariable int userid)
What query should I use in my class??

Comment: Look at Spring JPA

Comment: just a suggestion regarding conventions: dont use hibernate(jpa) session in controller, always use a service class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from IterationInfo WHERE userId=:userId");
query.setParameter("userId", userid);
IterationInfo iterationinfo=query.uniqueResult();  // Returns null if not found
```

I cannot see your IterationInfo class, so I'm not 100% sure on the name of the field there (I assumed `userId`).

Comment: I tried and found a way..Query query=session.createQuery("from iterationInfo where userid="+userid);...userid is int with getters/setters in the IterationInfo

Answer (score 0):

Try this this may help you.

```
String hql = "from iterationInfo WHERE userId=:userId";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("userId", userid);
List<IterationInfo> iterationinfolist = query.list();
```